# Fullpath of image in tutorial?

Tags: image, files-and-directories

Is it possible to figure out the fullpath of an image in tutorial ?

For example, we can find an image of duck in tutorial/ImageProcessing.

But it is not easy to figure out the fullpath of the image.

`Get Image Information` doesn't provide its fullpath.

[image]

Comment: The path of the Notebook with this picture is in: `C:\Users\..username..\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\...MMA version e.g. 13.1...\Documentation\English\System\Tutorials\ImageProcessing.nb`

Comment: Thank you, I verified that the image of tutorial does not exist separately as an image file, it is melted in the .nb file.

Comment: You can `Export` it to a file.